# How to collect async response using RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java, kotlin, rx-java2

Here is my goal: collect responses from async tasks that come from a third party library

requirement: use RxJava2 to accomplish in order

I'm stuck at thinking use which operator or operators to do so, ideas are appreciated.

My thought is:

```
Flowable.fromIterable(list)
    .anOperatorCanOnNextTheResponse()
    .buffer()
    .subscribe(newList)
```

Comment: Can you show us where you got stuck with the things you have tried?

Comment: @nhaarman I updated my question.

Comment: I guess you can collect responses in onNext method in you subscriber and use all collected in onCompleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have accomplish by using PublishProcessor, PublishSubject can also do the trick, but I skip the difference between them.

```
val mPublishProcessor: FlowableProcessor<String> = PublishProcessor.create<String>().toSerialized()

list.forEach {
    doSomeAsyncTasksWithCallback(string) {
      mPublishProcessor.onNext(string)
    }
}

mPublishProcessor
.buffer(list.size)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe {
   doSomethingWithTheCollectedStrings()
}
```

Comment: You probably want to `subscribeOn` just before `subscribe`. Otherwise the buffer operation will take place in Android's main thread

Comment: Thanks for the tips, it should observeOn main thread after buffer()